# twitter search API always return null geolocation

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j java library to make a twitter API search for given keywords. The rearch works fine, but all the tweets returned have the `geo` field set to `null`.
I have taken a look to the twitter developers [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) and all te results there, have `geo` null.

Here is my java code:

```
TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory();
Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
Query query = new Query("query");
query.setRpp(10);
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

I list all the tweets but none of them has geo code.

Is there any way I can get the geo location of the tweet /user?

Comment: Well are you sure that those results have a geo parameter set? It's an optional field that may or may not be there.

Comment: I will try to see that, but I have made many queries, and no geo location found.

Comment: Well try finding a user that is tagging the posts with a geolocation. You could always make an account and post a tagged tweet.

Comment: Indeed, posts that were not geotagged will not return anything. They are not automatically geotagged.

Comment: I have searched for my own tweets, adding geolocation, I find the tweet, but still no geolocation.

Comment: Edit: I get only the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a [problem at Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/141) causing this behaviour.

Although [some search queries](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=TheBeautiful_NI%20thanks) work for me and return some coordinates (1st of Feb 2012).

Unfortunately what I can only suggest is waiting until they solve the problem or have a look at the discussion attached to that issue.